# Configure Mouse Middle(Wheel) button to bring behind window in focus

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, mouse

In Ubuntu, whenever you press the middle scroll wheel of the mouse at top of a window, it brings  the window immediately behind the current window into focus.

How can this be done in Windows 7?

Comment: By installing Ubuntu? Seriously, though, it sounds like you might be able to do something like this with AutoHotKey.

Comment: Yes in ubuntu I do this every time whenever i have to bring behind window in focus. I will surely give this AutoHotKey a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can get AutoHotKey from [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

AutoHotKey helps you configure your mouse buttons and keyboard buttons to perform certain script operation that the user specifies. That means the user can code what a specific button press will do.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) on How to write your own scripts..

If coding is not your thing, there is a [package](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/91577-taskbarnavigation-switch-windows-in-taskbar-order-alt-tab-replacement/) which almost does what you want..

Comment: Perhaps more detail would make this a good answer.  As it is, it will likely be deleted as a Link Only answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sure will add more details.. Thanks for pointing this out..:)